# JQUERY: Change value from text input having a checkbox selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, input, checkbox

I need to change the value of a text input only if a checkbox is selected. Both inputs (text and checkbox) have the same class:

```
        <label for="text_to_apply">Write your text: </label>
        <input type="text" id="text_to_apply" name="text_to_apply" value="">
        <button type="button" id="btn_apply">Change</button>

        <form id="theform">
            <input type="text" value="1" id="one1" class="one"><input type="checkbox" id="one1_" class="one"><br>
            <input type="text" value="1" id="one2" class="one"><input type="checkbox" id="one2_" class="one"><br>
            <input type="text" value="1" id="one3" class="one"><input type="checkbox" id="one3_" class="one"><br>
            <input type="text" value="1" id="one4" class="one"><input type="checkbox" id="one4_" class="one"><br>
            <input type="text" value="2" id="two1" class="two"><input type="checkbox" id="two1_" class="two"><br>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script>
        $('#btn_apply').click(function() {
            var mytext = $('#text_to_apply').val();
            if ($('#theform').find('.one input:checked')) {
                $('#theform').find('.one:text').attr('value', mytext);
            }
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

I am running out of ideas. Please Help!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your question right - it will look like this:

```
    $('#btn_apply').click(function() {
        if ($('#yourCheckboxId').is(':checked')){
             $('#inputId').val('some text you want');
        }            
    });
```

Here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Goodluck/2XBcK/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    $('#btn_apply').click(function() {
        var mytext = $('#text_to_apply').val();
        $('#theform').find('input:checked').each(function(){
            $(this).prev().val(mytext);
        });
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/98Rhc/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no `:text` in jQuery that I'm aware of. Presuming your HTML stays the same, you can use the `.prev()` method to target the input before each `input:checked`.

```
    $('#btn_apply').click(function() {
        var mytext = $('#text_to_apply').val();
        if ($('#theform').find('input:checked')) {
            $('#theform').find('input:checked').prev('input').attr('value', mytext);
        }
    });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/willthemoor/5qmH8/